# Scroll a div on a webpage without scrolling the main page in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

How can I handle nested scroll bars on Firefox using Selenium Webdriver? The functionality I am trying to automate is that on scrolling down the whole frame, Next button gets enabled. I tried javascript executor, but it scrolls the main page and not inside the div. I also tried it using Actions, please see my code below:

```
WebElement snapshot_list = driver.findElement(By.id("snapshots-list"));
Actions scrolldown = new Actions(driver);

scrolldown.moveToElement(snapshot_list).build().perform();
snapshot_list.click();

scrolldown.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform();
```

It does not result in any error, the testcase appears as Passed in TestNG but it simply skips the scrolldown.keyDown part. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: why do you need `scrolldown.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.END).perform(); `part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already mentioned that you tried Javascript Executor, however don't know what all you tried. If you have already tried below, ignore them.

```
(((JavascriptExecutor)driver)).executeScript("document.getElementById('snapshots-list').scrollIntoView({ 
  behavior: 'smooth' 
});");
```

or

```
(((JavascriptExecutor)driver)).executeScript("document.getElementById('snapshots-list').scrollIntoView(true);");
```

or

```
(((JavascriptExecutor)driver)).executeScript("jQuery(\"snapshots-list\").mouseover();");
```

or click immediately after moving to element as mentioned below

```
WebElement snapshot_list = driver.findElement(By.id("snapshots-list"));
Actions scrolldown = new Actions(driver);

scrolldown.moveToElement(snapshot_list).click().build().perform();
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it through the Actions with a little tweaking and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked for me to scroll the div-

```
WebElement eleAssistanceInput = driver.findElement(By.id("abc"));
//the above element will be visible after scrolling down the div.                       
                        ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", eleAssistanceInput);

                        eleAssistanceInput.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I achieved it through Actions, I focused an element in the frame and inside a while loop I added the following condition:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(FirstSnapshot).build().perform();
FirstSnapshot.click();

while(Nextbutton.isEnabled()== false)
        {
        action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).perform();
        }
System.out.println("Button is enabled");
```